# Error con routing module y captura de id ANGULAR

Tags: angular, rutas

Tengo un problema muy peculiar. Tengo una ruta que me devuelve un objeto con información: `http://localhost:4200/empresa/pasarela/formadepago/75202`.

Recojo el id con el observable de angular como viene en la documentación y funciona bien.
Este es el link que me provee el id: `<a [routerLink]="['/empresa/pasarela/formadepago', item.id]">CONTRATAR</a>`

El problema cuando quiero acceder desde otra ruta o si refresco la página, el observable no lee el id y me aparece este error en consola: 
`GET http://localhost:4200/empresa/pasarela/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

parece que no estoy escribiendo la ruta bien en el router-module.ts o qué será que me falla?

Alguien podría ayudarme con esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: A]

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta por mí mismo pero la publicaré por si alguien algún día le pasa lo que a mí.

Me he dado cuenta que en los proyectos de angular las rutas deben ser consideradas por el `base href=""` del **index.html**

Cuanto más largas hagas las rutas del proyecto, se deben considerar saltos arriba en esta etiqueta. En mi ejemplo: 
Si son 4 subpáginas se deben añadir 3 saltos `<base href="../../../">`
Y si usaré la etiqueta de `/:id` esta también cuenta como salto, así que lo solucioné agregando un salto más:  `<base href="../../../../">`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tenia el mismo problema por mas de 3 dias busca y busca y nada, me haz salvado (:

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió, eso fue hace casi un año y con angular 7. Pero hoy en día dejo el href="/" y me trabaja sin problemas en las versiones 8 y 9 de angular. Te recomiendo que intentes poner la base así... por cierto, te agradecería que calificaras mi respuesta y mi pregunta. Saludos